# Transpose in excel doesn't work, it just copies one cell

Tags: excel, transpose

I've been researching for quite a while and I cannot find the solution to this problem. I need to switch the values of some rows and columns in excel and I saw that I could use transpose, put the array I need to swap and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

I am doing that but the result is that it just copies a single cell, the 1st one, nothing happens to the other ones selected in the array.

I am using Office 2010 and this is the result. Any idea what could be happening and how I could fix it? 
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select a 2 col by 3 rows range before entering the formula, e.g.

[image]

The range can be larger - then all result cells not included in the (untransposed) source range are filled witn #N/A; if the result range is too small (like in your example) you get only a subset of your source table transposed.

Comment: yeep ... with array formulas in general you first select the range, then enter the formula in the active cell (without curly braces), then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 3):

Select **E8** through **F10** and array enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:C2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!!!!!!

I was entering the formula without selecting the cells and that was not working. It was driving my crazy....

Cheers